# Procedure to recover from failed Cassandra bootstrap

Tags: cassandra, bootstrapping, recovery

**Scenario**: New node was added to a Cassandra cluster. The node was gossiped, got token range assigned, but by mistake Cassandra was manually brought down via "service stop cassandra" before any streaming from peers started. We also never saw the node in UJ status. Upon this node restart we see it in UN mode and commit log files are growing, but not much data in data directory. One of our KS has RF=1 on it.

**Question**: What is the best procedure to recover from this? The concerns are not to loose data from RF=1 keyspace and ensure streaming of the data to a new node worked properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a new node in 2 ways:

1. Set auto_bootstrap of the new node to true and join the cluster
2. Set auto_bootstrap of the new node to false and join the cluster. Manually do a repair to stream the data and correct your replicas in your node.

Once you have added a new node. Your old nodes will have old tokens and some old data also, which will not be deleted until you do a cleanup on old nodes after new node is successfully added.

In your case you have mistakenly stopped the new node in the middle. So you can follow the below steps to correct the replicas and check your nodetool status to check load is distributed to the new node:

1. Do a full repair. (In case of Cassandra 2.2 and above by default it runs in incremental repair. So check and do a full repair and no incremental repair)
2. Check nodetool status data is streamed and load is distributed to the new node

Comment: The repair is very important here. If one would do nodetool rebuild, the data for the keyspaces with RF=1 won't be streamed to a new node.